# Kubernetes Ingress Controller uses the default certificates instead of the certificates provided in the secret

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, proxy, kubernetes-helm

I am having an issue where the Ingress controller running in one namespace is unable to read the certificates defined for an ingress (in another namespace) and is using the default certificates.

```
Error getting SSL certificate "connectivity-proxy/cdf-conn-proxy-ingress-secret": local SSL certificate connectivity-proxy/cdf-conn-proxy-ingress-secret was not found. Using default certificate
```

Is there any additional access that needs to be enabled for this? The secret description is as follows

```
kubectl get secret/cdf-conn-proxy-ingress-secret -n=connectivity-proxy -o yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ca.crt: <Base 64 encoded data>
  tls.crt: <Base 64 encoded data>
  tls.key: <Base 64 encoded data>
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1",
      "data":{"ca.crt":<Base 64 encoded data>,
      "tls.crt":<Base 64 encoded data>,
      "tls.key":<Base 64 encoded data>,
      "kind":"Secret","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"cdf-conn-proxy-ingress-secret","namespace":"connectivity-proxy"},"type":"kubernetes.io/tls"}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-03-03T02:05:53Z"
  name: cdf-conn-proxy-ingress-secret
  namespace: connectivity-proxy
  resourceVersion: "3679739774"
  uid: 2016a8dc-e9c7-40a4-a3f8-131526fa591b
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

The ingress description is as follows:

```
kubectl get ingress/connectivity-proxy-tunnel -o yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "10"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "120"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "120"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: connectivity-proxy
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: connectivity-proxy
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: connectivity-proxy/connectivity-ca-connectivity-proxy
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "10"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: "proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Client-Cert
      $ssl_client_escaped_cert;    \n"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "10"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "120"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "120"
    nginx.org/websocket-services: connectivity-proxy
  creationTimestamp: "2024-03-06T17:45:36Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: connectivity-proxy
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: connectivity-proxy-2.11.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: connectivity-proxy
  name: connectivity-proxy-tunnel
  namespace: connectivity-proxy
  resourceVersion: "3706227012"
  uid: 6dcfe450-91da-4d80-8821-85c9513b77b9
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: connectivity-proxy.cs-dev.transparent-proxy.eurekacloud.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: connectivity-proxy-tunnel-0
            port:
              number: 8042
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: connectivity-proxy-tunnel
            port:
              number: 8042
        path: /connectivity
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - connectivity-proxy.cs-dev.transparent-proxy.eurekacloud.io
    secretName: cdf-conn-proxy-ingress-secret
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 20.62.220.254
```

Comment: As you are using `Helm chart` and `ingress-nginx`, you need to specify `default-ssl-certificate` command line argument which is accepted by the Ingress controller. You need to update it by using the below mentioned command in `controller.extraArgs`.

`
--set controller.extraArgs.default-ssl-certificate="__NAMESPACE__/_SECRET__"
`

Comment: You can find more information in the [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/e079486d4dc40387389adbaed7ec9b80d897d810/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L180) link and [command line arguments](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/cli-arguments/).

Comment: Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know if the above comments helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed revert. The root cause was that the RSA certificate used was of the type

-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- -----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- instead of

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Because of this the Ingress controller was unable to read it, and threw an exception. Took sime to figure this out, as I did not have access to the ingress controller. Thanks a lot BTW for your answers